# Javascript array string generator with multiple settings?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, radio-button

I'm using a single button (function 'newThing') to generate one array string at a time, which is displayed above the button. The user can choose which array to pull the string from using the radio boxes on the right, and they can use the radio boxes on the left to choose the order that each item generates. In the javascript provided, 'mode1' is the random setting, 'mode2' is the old-new setting and 'mode3' is the new-old setting. The random setting works perfectly, but I haven't been able to figure out how to generate the items in a specific order using the other two modes. What should go under the 'if(mode2.checked)' and 'if(mode3.checked)' so that it displays one string at a time in chronological order for mode2 and reverse chronological order for mode3?

```js
function newThing() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  if (mode1.checked) {
    if (drawingCheck.checked) {
      var randomDrawing = Math.floor(Math.random() * (odddrawing.length));
      document.getElementById("thingDisplay").innerHTML = odddrawing[randomDrawing];
    }
    if (haikuCheck.checked) {
      var randomHaiku = Math.floor(Math.random() * (oddhaiku.length));
      document.getElementById("thingDisplay").innerHTML = oddhaiku[randomHaiku];
    }
  }
  if (mode2.checked) {
    if (drawingCheck.checked) {

    }
    if (haikuCheck.checked) {

    }
  }
  if (mode3.checked) {
    if (drawingCheck.checked) {

    }
    if (haikuCheck.checked) {

    }
  }
}

//drawing array
var odddrawing = [
  '<p>20191201 \<br> this is a drawing \<br> this is a drawing \<br> this is a drawing</p>',
  '<p>20191202 \<br> help help \<br> help help help \<br> help help help help</p>',
  '<p>20191203 \<br> go in order \<br> generate in order plz \<br> this is a drawing</p>'
]
//haiku array
var oddhaiku = [
  '<p>20191204_2249 \<br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem</p>',
  '<p>20191205_1206 \<br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem</p>',
  '<p>20191206_0816 <br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem</p>',
  '<p>20191207_1852 \<br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem \<br> this is a poem</p>'
]
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #111;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/*start checkbox design*/

input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='radio']:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input[type='radio']:checked {
  background: #888;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 3px;
  top: 13px;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#categories {
  user-select: none;
}

#mode {
  user-select: none;
}


/*end checkbox design*/


/*start new thing button*/

#button01 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-color: #888;
  border-width: 6px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
}

#button01:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#button01:active {
  background-color: #777;
  transition: 0.1s;
}


/*end new thing button*/

#thingDisplay {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 170%;
}


/*start page container*/

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 820px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.cell {
  color: white;
}

.cell-1 {
  /*display*/
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  min-height: 580px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cell-2 {
  /*button*/
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.cell-3 {
  /*mode*/
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1%;
}

.cell-4 {
  /*blank, REMOVE*/
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.cell-5 {
  /*categories*/
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1%;
}

.cell-6 {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/*end page container*/

form {
  color: #FFF;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell cell-1">
    <div align="center" id='thingDisplay'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell-2">
    <button class="box" id="button01" onclick="newThing()">New Thing</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell-3">
    <form id="mode">
      <label><input type="radio" name="modes" id="mode1" checked="yes" /> Random </label>
      <br /><label><input type="radio" name="modes" id="mode2" /> Old - New </label>
      <br /><label><input type="radio" name="modes" id="mode3" /> New - Old </label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="cell cell-5" align="right">
    <form id="categories">
      <label> Drawings <input type="radio" name="thing" id="drawingCheck" /></label>
      <br /><label> Haiku <input type="radio" name="thing" id="haikuCheck" /></label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using a single button

Comment: What do you mean by "chronological order"? Also you are only showing one item

Comment: Each string in the two elements will be titled with the date they were created. For example, if one of the arrays had an image, the string would look like this: '20200616.png' but I didn't include these names in my examples to simplify my problem. You are correct, the random mode is showing only one string at a time. My problem lies with the 'old-new' and 'new-old' functions. Rather than displaying one string randomly, these other two modes will allow the user to see one string at a time in chronological order, either from oldest to newest or visa versa.